# Ansible Gather Facts SSH Issues

Tags: ssh, ansible

I am patching a MYSQL server using ansible. However I need to perform various tasks before applying the patches. One of the tasks is to stop all running services on the background servers. The qa_bg_servers is a group of 3 IP addresses in my hosts file. So within my playbook, I have the yaml code below:

The start of the playbook is this:

```yaml
---
- name: Update to MYSQL Server
  hosts: " {{ host }} "
  gather_facts: no
  serial: 1
```

```yaml
    - name: Run powershell script to stop all running services01 services on background servers
      ansible.windows.win_powershell:
        script: |
          Stop-Service -DisplayName services01*
      delegate_to: " {{ background_servers }} "
```

The error I get is (the IP address is not the real IP address):

```
fatal: [11.111.2.44 -> backgroud_servers]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname background_servers: Temporary failure in name resolution", "unreachable": true}
```

The windows script works as I have used it in other playbooks. I also normally SSH into the Ansible controller. The issue here is the IP addresses in the "delegate_to" are having ssh connection issues.

Comment: `delegate_to` expects a single server (inventory_)name or ip, not a group nor a list of ips. If you want tu run a specific task on a specific group, just add an other play in your playbook targeting that group and don't delegate.

Comment: It worked using only the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

As [Zeitounator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9401096/zeitounator) pointed out, you can't delegate_to on a list, which is what it seems you're doing.  You could however loop through each of the nodes in that list, by adding a loop:

```yaml
    - name: Run powershell script to stop all running services01 services on background servers
      ansible.windows.win_powershell:
        script: |
          Stop-Service -DisplayName services01*
      delegate_to: " {{ item }} "
      loop: "{{ background_servers }}"
```